# Divergence theorem given $\overset{\rightharpoonup} F = x \hat{i} + y \hat{j} +z \hat{k}$ and the volume

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, divergence-theorem

I am trying to calculate $\iint\limits_S \overset{\rightharpoonup} F \cdot \overset{\rightharpoonup} n\ dS$ using the divergence theorem.

It is given that $\overset{\rightharpoonup} F = x \hat{i} + y \hat{j} +z \hat{k}$ and $V$ is a 3-dimensional object having volume $4$ bounded by the surface $S$.

Here are the steps I have taken:

*Divergence theorem*

$$\iint\limits_S \overset{\rightharpoonup} F \cdot \overset{\rightharpoonup} n\ dS = \iiint\limits_V \text{div} \overset{\rightharpoonup} F dx\ dy\ dz$$

*Find the divergence of* $\overset{\rightharpoonup} F$

$$\text{div} \overset{\rightharpoonup} F = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}x + \frac{\partial}{\partial y}y + \frac{\partial}{\partial z}z = 3$$

*Substitute into the divergence theorem*

$$\iiint\limits_V (3)\ dx\ dy\ dz$$

$$3 \cdot \iiint\limits_V\ dx\ dy\ dz$$

*Given the volume is 4,*

$$\iint\limits_S \overset{\rightharpoonup} F \cdot \overset{\rightharpoonup} n\ dS = 3 \cdot 4 = 12$$

Is this correct?

My main doubt is whether it is permissible to replace $\iiint\limits_V\ dx\ dy\ dz$ with $4$ in the last step.

Comment: Why do you have doubts?

Comment: @user I am unsure if the triple integral represents the volume and can be replaced with 4. Based on my understanding, it seems like it should work, but I'd like to confirm.

Comment: Surely. Applying the divergence theorem one integrates over the volume inside the surface. You are of course lucky that the divergence is just a constant.

Comment: Thanks, @user! That helps.

Comment: fun fact: this factor of $3$ that you obtain is precisely the factor of $3$ appearing in the surface area of the unit sphere ($4\pi$) vs the volume of the unit ball ($\frac{4\pi}{3}$)